Derivative of a time-reversed unit step function?
I understand the idea of the unit step function and the Dirac delta, and that the delta can be seen as the "generalised" derivative of the former. But what about if we had to differentiate a time-reversed unit step, i.e., $u(-t)$?
My basic understanding is that we'd get another delta, but with a weight of (-1) instead due to chain rule, i.e., the derivative would just be $-\delta(t)$ since it's zero elsewhere for all time. But if we then had to reverse this operation by taking the indefinite integral, would we not end up getting a result of $-u(t)$ instead of the original $u(-t)$? It seems like we're basically missing an "offset" of $+1$ in this solution?
What am I missing here? Please advise, thanks :)

Your statements are all correct and you can also see this by writing $u(-t) = 1 - u(t)$ (for the step function defined with $u(0) = 1/2$). That you loose information about the $+1$ Is not surprising since derivatives don’t care about additive constants.

Interesting, thanks for the comment! So if I were to do a time-domain convolution using $u(-t)$ as the input signal, I wouldn't be able to exploit the "derivative property" of convolution here? I tried doing this earlier and this is what led me to the problem, and I suppose losing the "+1" is the reason why it wasn't working?

Can you explain what you mean by exploiting the derivative property of the convolution?

The property basically says that $\dot{y}(t) = h(t) \ast \dot{x}(t)$. So for example, if $x(t) = u(t)$ then $\dot{x}(t) = \delta(t)$, and thus $\dot{y}(t)$ is just $h(t)$; so taking the indefinite integral of $h(t)$ would produce $y(t)$. However this clearly won't work if $x(t) = u(-t)$ as we're now losing out on information since $\dot{x}(t) = -\delta(t)$ in this case. Maybe I'm missing something...

Thanks. I am not sure what you find problematic. For $x(t) = u(t)$ you get $\dot{y} = h$ and for $x(t) = u(-t) = 1 - u(t)$ you get $\dot{y} = -h$.

Yep. The problem I have is that I take the integral of $-h(t)$, I end up with a different result to just doing the convolution integral. For example, if I take $h(t) = e^{-t}u(t)$, then I just need to integrate the negative of this, which gives me a right-sided function as my $y(t)$. But if I use the convolution integral directly, with $x$ and $h$ as above, I end up with a function that spans ALL time (not just right-sided). Maybe I'm doing something wrong though.

For instance, using the convolution integral, I flip and shift $x$ so that it becomes $x(t-\lambda)$ and then multiply this with $h(\lambda)$ and integrate over all $\lambda$. So for negative $t$, I integrate $x(t-\lambda) h(\lambda)$ from 0 to Inf on the $\lambda$ axis and this gives me a value of 1, which implies that $y(t)$ is 1 for all negative t (if I worked this out correctly). But this disagrees with the derivative property which says that $y$ is purely right-sided!

Ahh, sorry, now I see. That’s just the problem that the integral of $\dot{y}$ from $-\infty$ to $t$ only equals $y$ up to an additive constant. For $x(t) = u(t)$ that constant vanishes because $y$ vanishes at $-\infty$. But for $x(t) = u(-t)$ you have that $y$ vanishes at $\infty$. So in this case you could take the integral from $\infty$ to $t$.

Ah interesting! Let me look into that further. I've heard that there are certain initial conditions that we assume/ignore so that the indefinite integral equation works, so perhaps that's what's tripping me up here. Thanks for your quick responses!

Look at $x\to \theta(x)$ as a unit step function with infinitimal smoothed corners and nearly infinite slope $x\to \theta_\lambda (x)$.
One may use the Gaussian distribution $$\theta_\lambda (x)=1/2 (1+ \text{erf}(x/\sqrt\lambda)).$$ Its derivative is a smooth Gaussian concentrated in a $6\lambda$-interval.
Use any technique developed for smooth functions and do the limit $\lambda\to 0, \theta_\lambda \to \theta, \delta_\lambda \to \delta $ at the end under an integral with a smooth function with compact support, that have nor surface termas in integration by parts.
Thats the very content of Schwartz distributions theory for distributions with point support, defined as linear forms by integration with a singular kernel.
